# When code reaches a UIImage or UIlabel modification it takes all objects back to their position in the storyboard

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, storyboard

I am trying to move an image as it changes .image direction along with movement (timer going on, selector is change of image.png direction). The thing is my code used to work until I changed the supporting files, I changed the .png images for new ones without background. I updated the new directions in the code:

```
        FirstImage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"NewImage1.png"];
```

//in the next timer selector run, it changes .image

```
        FirstImage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"NewImage2.png"];
```

//and then it goes back to the first one in the next timer selector run

When I run the code without the change of .image, the rest of the program works just fine. That means Images move up and down the screen as they are meant to.
But when I run the code with the .image changes, it freezes for a moment, it does change .image but returns the UIImage to its original position in the storyboard.

Hope someone can help.

Comment: Must add I've already had this problem before, when trying to change a UILabel .text in every timer selector execution, every single object in the screen went back to its position in the storyboard.

Comment: You have not supplied enough code to troubleshoot your issue.  All you have supplied is how you are assigning an image but not how you are moving it which it appears is part of your problem.  Also, don't capitalize variable names, that should be reserved for classes.  You should have it as firstImage.  This is not the cause of your issue, however.

Comment: Hey @C6Silver. Sorry for nit supplying enough code, the thing is it's a complex program with many local variables set all over and would make it look messy. I tried to illustrate the issue verbally because I've read of other people who seem to have had the same problem, only in latest versions of Xcode, so far with no solution. It is a specific problem though, consisting in a position reset to the storyboard main view every single time the timer selector executes.